# Session lost on Laravel Dusk using Laravel Sail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail to run a small Laravel project. I would like to add some Dusk tests to it but I'm stuck on a problem which I believe is related to the session being lost.

All tests that don't require authentication work, however, when I try to manually authenticate a user inside of the test and then dd it, it returns null.

This is my code:

```
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->loginAs(User::find(1));
            dd(auth()->user()); <--- null is returned here
             
            // if i try to access any login protected page here
            // it redirects me to the login page
        });
```

I didn't change the default .env file so there are no custom configuration settings and I've followed the steps showed in the documentation to setup dusk with sail (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#laravel-dusk).

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: when you call dd(auth()->user()), you're attempting to dump the authenticated user from the PHP process running the test

Comment: thanks for your reply. I understand that, but what about the next bit? I mean, if I try to access a protected route (a route that requires authentication in order to be accessed), it redirects me to the login page (it looks like the session is lost).

Comment: 1- Ensure your session is configured correctly in your Laravel application. Check your `config/session.php` file and `.env` file for correct session driver
2- Laravel Dusk may use a different environment file, like `.env.dusk.local` or  `.env.dusk` Make sure this file exists and has the correct environment settings for your Dusk tests, especially the APP_URL, database

Comment: If you need to debug or output information from within the Dusk browser session, you can use methods like `$browser->dump()` to output the current state of the browser, or `$browser->screenshot('screenshot_name')` to take a screenshot of the current page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've manually created a .env.dusk.local file and tried setting the session to array and file with no success. I've also set the APP_URL to laravel.test, localhost but also no success. What am I missing?